# Sort a list of dicts by multiple keys

Tags: python, list, sorting

I'd like to sort a list of dicts based on the rank of multiple values in the dicts. But the sort returns None as is

**Code:**

```
def site_attr_rank(d):
    return attr_rank[d['site']], lang_rank[d['lang']]
attr_rank = {'apple':0, 'pear':1, 'banana':2}
lang_rank = {'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':2}
print 'items 1\n', x['items']
x['items'] = x['items'].sort(key=site_attr_rank)
print 'items 2\n', x['items']
```

Comment: `.sort` sorts in place. You will want to use `x['items'].sort(...)` without using the result.

Comment: @androyd Yes. That was the problem. Thank you

Comment: I'll post it as an answer so you can mark the question answered.

Comment: Or, if you _do_ want to get a value back to assign somewhere, use `sorted(x)`, not `x.sort()`. (This leaves `x` unchanged and gives you a brand-new sorted list.)

Comment: Also, this is explained in the tutorial, in the FAQ, in the built-in `help(list.sort)` or `help(x['items'].sort)`, in the Sorting HOWTO, and in the online docs. Next time you're baffled by a function's behavior, look it up and you will usually find the answer immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.sort` sorts in place and modifies the list. You will want to use `x['items'].sort(...)` without using the result (which is always `None`).